# How to add overlay with diagonally up effect using ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

I am trying to add overlay image with diagonally but no luck yet.
I want to add overlay with diagonally up effect using ffmpeg like below video.
https://www.screencast.com/t/bZfnHXsJhrPH
can you please help me to creating this type of video using ffmpeg or something else that can i use for this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Most if not all video editors will have transition effects built into them. You can use one of the many open source video editors such as openShot and add your transitions.

OpenShot website: http://www.openshot.org

Transitions in openShot: http://www.openshotusers.com/help/1.3/en/ar01s19.html

Apart from that, it's going to be a lot of work adding your own transitions to a video, which is just re-inventing the wheel.